# How can I store in a variable the Firestore document data what I read from the database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I Would like to read a data from cloud firestore and store it in a variable. I tried in many ways, but i get 'null' in every time.

the code is :

```
 class Graph extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GraphState createState() => _GraphState();
}
class _GraphState extends State<Graph> {

  var totalCalories;
  Future<void> getData() async {
    DocumentSnapshot ds =await  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('calories')
        .doc('01')
        .get();
    final _totalCalories = ds.data()['totalCalories'];
    setState(() {
      totalCalories = _totalCalories;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(totalCalories.toString()),
    );
  }

}
```

Please help me! :(

Comment: Do you get an error? What happens if you put your code in a try/catch block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to this:

String totalCalories = "waiting";

And add `initstate` to your widget:

```
String totalCalories = "waiting"; 
  Future<void> getData() async {
    DocumentSnapshot ds =await  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('calories')
        .doc('01')
        .get();
    final _totalCalories = ds.data()['totalCalories'];
    setState(() {
      totalCalories = _totalCalories;
    });
  }
@override
initState() {
  super.initState();
 getData(); // add getData here
}
```

It should work.

Comment: Honestly thank you 

Comment: You're most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You did not even call `getData()`, did you? Variables are initialized with null. `totalCalories` is still null when you use it because you didn't assign a value to it after initialization.

Use a `FutureBuilder` with `getData()` as a future to await the query to complete. Return the `Text` widget in the builder function if the snapshot's `connectionState` property is `ConnectionState.done`. In the `else` block, you can return something like a loading spinner.